# Reload vue component in spa project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

so i am creating spa app with vue js and i have these route

```
{ path: '/artikel/create',name: 'artikelCreate', components: { default: artikel_form, 'header': header} },
{ path: '/artikel/edit/:id',name: 'artikelEdit', components: { default: artikel_form, 'header': header}, meta: { mode:'edit' } },
```

there is `artikelCreate` route that create a blank form from `artikel_form` component and there is also `artikelEdit` route that create a form with data according to the `:id`. Both of them using the same component which is `artikel_form`

i am creating it like that so i don't need to create 2 form component that have a nearly identical. And i just use `if(this.$route.meta.mode === 'edit')` to determine is this route is `artikelEdit` or `artikelCreate` and do some methods based on that information.

It works just fine but then i face some issue by doing this step:

1. If i go to `artikelEdit` route then it will create `artikel_form` component alongside the data for each input and other stuff
2. But because i have a navigation bar then i can from `artikelEdit` route access or navigate to `artikelCreate` route and if i click/navigate to those route it should create  an empty `artikel_form`
3. The problem is the route is changing but it didn't create an empty `artikel_form` it still showing `artikel_form` from `artikelEdit` route

So how to just reset or maybe recreate those component? i know, i can just make a `v-model` and clean those `v-model` but sometimes there is some component inside that just need extra step than simply cleaning `v-model` that tied into `input text` on the form. And it also prone to error since we need to specify each one.

Is there any elegant way to just call reload or refresh or recreate component in vue?

Comment: Hi, to react to params changes in the same component, you can simply watch the `$route` object. You can have a look in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Answer (score 0):

It's because Vue thinks that it's the same component (same object reference), so even when the route change, the component still points to the same reference, so Vue doesn't reload the component.

So we need to clone the artikel_form so that they have different reference.
We can use [object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
{
    path: '/artikel/create',
    name: 'artikelCreate',
    components: {
        default: {...artikel_form},
        'header': header
    }
},
{
    path: '/artikel/edit/:id',
    name: 'artikelEdit',
    components: {
        default: {...artikel_form},
        'header': header
    },
    meta: {
        mode:'edit'
    }
},
```